# MS access DB and SQL from same query error

Tags: ms-access

I use MS access DB and SQL and have table2 I don't know how can I got this result

```
name | total | ER| OPD | IPD
CRP  |   4   | 1 |  2  |  1
BRUA |   1   | 1 |  0  |  0
BRUB |   2   | 0 |  1  |  1
total|   7   | 2 |  3  |  2
```

I use this code but when I save file I got this error Circular reference caused by query reference

```
       SELECT 'CRP' AS name,
        count (CRP) AS total,
        (select COUNT(CRP) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER' and CRP<>"") AS ER, 
        (SELECT COUNT(CRP) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD' and CRP<>"" ) AS OPD, 
        (SELECT COUNT(CRP) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD' and CRP <> "" ) AS IPD
        FROM Table2 
        where CRP <> "" 

    UNION ALL

        SELECT 'BRUA' AS name,
        count (BRUA) AS total,
        (select COUNT(BRUA) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER' and BRUA<>''  ) AS ER, 
        (SELECT COUNT(BRUA) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD' and BRUA<>'' ) AS OPD, 
        (SELECT COUNT(BRUA) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD' and BRUA <> '' ) AS IPD
        FROM Table2 
        where BRUA <> ''

         UNION ALL SELECT 'BRUB' AS name,
        count (BRUB) AS total,
        (select COUNT(BRUB) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER' and BRUB<>'') AS ER, 
        (SELECT COUNT(BRUB) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD' and BRUB<>'') AS OPD, 
        (SELECT COUNT(BRUB) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD' and BRUB <> '' ) AS IPD
        FROM Table2 
        where BRUB <> ''

         UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'Total' AS name, Sum(total) AS total1, Sum(ER) AS ER1, 
Sum(OPD) AS OPD1, Sum(IPD) AS IPD1

        from sertable;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that it can't tell the difference between the column `BRUB` in

```
select COUNT(BRUB) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER' and BRUB<>''
```

and the `BRUB` in

```
SELECT 'BRUB' AS name,
count (BRUB) AS total,
(...) AS ER
FROM Table2 
where BRUB <> ''
```

You can make your aliasing explicit like this

```
SELECT 'CRP' AS name,
count(T1.CRP) AS total,
(select COUNT(Tcrp.CRP) FROM Table2 Tcrp WHERE Section='ER' and CRP<>"") AS ER, 
(SELECT COUNT(Tcrp.CRP) FROM Table2 Tcrp WHERE Section='OPD' and CRP<>"" ) AS OPD, 
(SELECT COUNT(Tcrp.CRP) FROM Table2 Tcrp WHERE Section = 'IPD' and CRP <> "" ) AS IPD
FROM Table2 T1
where T1.CRP <> "" 

UNION ALL   SELECT 'BRUA' AS name,
count(T2.BRUA) AS total,
(select COUNT(Tbrua.BRUA) FROM Table2 Tbrua WHERE Tbrua.Section='ER' and Tbrua.BRUA <>''  ) AS ER, 
(SELECT COUNT(Tbrua.BRUA) FROM Table2 Tbrua WHERE Tbrua.Section='OPD' and Tbrua.BRUA <>'' ) AS OPD, 
(SELECT COUNT(Tbrua.BRUA) FROM Table2 Tbrua WHERE Tbrua.Section = 'IPD' and Tbrua.BRUA <> '' ) AS IPD
FROM Table2 T2
where T2.BRUA <> ''

UNION ALL SELECT 'BRUB' AS name,
count(BRUB) AS total,
(select COUNT(Tbrub.BRUB) FROM Table2 Tbrub WHERE Tbrub.Section='ER' and Tbrub.BRUB<>'') AS ER, 
(SELECT COUNT(Tbrub.BRUB) FROM Table2 Tbrub WHERE Tbrub.Section='OPD' and Tbrub.BRUB<>'') AS OPD, 
(SELECT COUNT(Tbrub.BRUB) FROM Table2 Tbrub WHERE Tbrub.Section = 'IPD' and Tbrub.BRUB <> '' ) AS IPD
FROM Table2 T3
where T3.BRUB <> ''

UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Total' AS name
, Sum(total) AS total1
, Sum(ER) AS ER1
, Sum(OPD) AS OPD1
, Sum(IPD) AS IPD1
from sertable;
```

Comment: the problem in sertable, last line

Comment: SELECT 'Total' AS name
, Sum(total) AS total1
, Sum(ER) AS ER1
, Sum(OPD) AS OPD1
, Sum(IPD) AS IPD1
from sertable;

Comment: @Masha2008 Why is that not selecting from `Table2` like the others?

Comment: because it gives total the count.

Comment: you can see the schedule up, I take the count from table2 and after that I use sum to get total.

Comment: Does that query work on it's own? i.e. not as a part of a union?

Comment: no, not work. I don't know how I can got total from the same query.